# Como Formatear, un dato en php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Como se podria formatear un dato que aparece la cifra junta.

123445567 € 1.234.456,7 €

poniendo un formato XX.XXX.XXX,XX

Seria con un echo number_format($total, 2',','.');

Comment: `echo number_format($total_compras, 2, '.' , ',')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 123445567;
echo number_format($total, 2, ",", ".");
```

sin embargo debes indicar los decimales si o si porque sino no sabes si tiene 1 decimal o 2 y no te va a tener en cuenta los centimos

```
$total = 12344556.07;

echo number_format($total, 2, ",", ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes instalada la extensión *intl* de PHP, una opción bastante interesante sería usar `NumberFormatter`, que tiene un formato específico para mostrar el importes:

```
<?php

    // Devuelve 123.445.567,00 € 
    echo NumberFormatter::create('es_ES', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY)->format(123445567);

?>
```